# Set-Acl on several Computers in AD via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, administrator

I have about 1000 computers that I have to set NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users allow-to-authenticate on.
I've tried to compose a script based on several google searches, but it doesn't work.

Please have a look at my script. Perhaps I am missing something.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-Location AD:\
$ALLDTPC = Get-Content H:\dtcomputer.txt
foreach ($PC In $ALLDTPC) {
    $ace = (Get-Acl "AD:$((Get-ADComputer $PC).DistinguishedName)").Access 
    foreach ($acl in $ace.Access) {
        $accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.ActiceDirectoryAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users", "Allow")
        $ace.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
        Set-Acl -AclObject $ace $PC.DistinguishedName -Verbose -Passthru
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting the ACEs from Get-Acl, then you are trying to retrieve ACEs again in the foreach

Answer (score 0):

I have no AD avaibable right now, but from what I've seen, you had an issue (`.access`) at line 6. I'm not sure, if the foreach loop does what you expect, maybe try it on one item first and review the results.

Try this code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-Location AD:\
$ALLDTPC = Get-Content H:\dtcomputer.txt
foreach ($PC In $ALLDTPC) {
    $ace = (Get-Acl "AD:$((Get-ADComputer $PC).DistinguishedName)").Access 
    foreach ($acl in $ace) {
        $accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.ActiceDirectoryAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users", "Allow")
        $ace.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
        Set-Acl -AclObject $ace $PC.DistinguishedName -Verbose -Passthru
    }
}
```